# Magento dropdown menu issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, magento, drop-down-menu

I have been working with a Magento site which is still under development. I have added a custom dropdown menu script and it works fine in the home page, 
**[zinnati.com](http://zinnati.com)**.

But in the following page and all inner pages, it disappears when the mouse is moved to a sub menu. 
**[www.zinnati.com/index.php/women.html](http://www.zinnati.com/index.php/women.html)**

I still cannot find the issue. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your main container of inner pages is overlapping on top navigation bar, thats why the hover effect on link dose not working on area where main container is overlapping.

now i have saw a minus margin on "header2" class
so you need to remove that for getting proper result.

try removing bottom margin.

`.header2 {width: 100%;padding: 0px;background-color: #000;/* margin-bottom: -10px; */}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! your solution fixed it. I cannot vote since I'm new. But really appreciate your help! May you be happy and prosperous always!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a link to the RELATIVE position of the col-lg-12 too

Try this on your style.css

```
.col-xs-1, ...... .col-lg-12 {
/* position: relative; */
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

It's fix the issue for me...

Be careful for the global positionning of your element with this settings...